# Dart Future wait to complete before calling another Future

Tags: flutter, dart, future

Looking for help here guys. I have 2 Futures that populate data in sqflite. I need one (_insertInitialData()) to finish first before calling the second one (_insertAdditionalData()). I have done it this way, but it's not working. It first does the re-recreation of the DB as expected, then both _insertInitialData() and _insertAdditionalData() not in the order I expected. I have tried .whenComplete and calling here _insertAdditionalData() and also have tried different ways that I think should work but nothing.

This is just something I'm doing for fun but still I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

TIA

````
Future<void> _insertAdditionalData() async{}

void populateDB() {
  try {
   final localDB = LocalDatabase.instance;
   Future.wait([localDB.dropDB(recreateDB: true)]).then((_){
    print('DB recreated!');
    Future.wait([_insertInitialData()]).then((_) {
     print('_insertInitialData done');
     Future.wait([_insertAdditionalData()]).then((_){
      print('_insertAdditionalData done');
     });
    });

   });
  } catch (ex) {
   print('There was a problem in populateDB(): $ex');
  }
 }```
````

Comment: check [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Comment: The purpose of `Future.wait` is to combine multiple `Future`s into a single `Future`.  Calling it on a `List` with only a single `Future` is pointless.  It's not possible for "DB recreated!", "_insertInitialData done", and "_insertAdditionalData done" to be printed out of order.  If you're observing that, then you probably called `populateDB` multiple times and are misinterpreting the output.  Otherwise post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Using `await` makes things a lot easier to read and will block execution of later lines until the action has finished.

```
Future<void> populateDB() async {
  final localDB = LocalDatabase.instance;
  await localDB.dropDB(recreateDB: true);
  print('DB recreated!');
  await _insertInitialData();
  print('_insertInitialData done');
  await _insertAdditionalData();
  print('_insertAdditionalData done');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried that, same result. I understand your code would do exactly the same thing I'm doing. I'm having the same output. mmm.. maybe is because what I'm doing inside those methods. They also are calling futures to insert data in the DB. They may be executing asynchornously.

Comment: You'd need to include that code for me to be able to comment on that. Feel free to update your question and I can update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I'll update this post after I check something!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using only one future statement, and follows it with multiple "then". This makes sure the first "then" will be completed before the second "then" is executed. I assume your `localDB.dropDB(recreateDB: true)` function is asynchronous.

```
Future<void> _insertAdditionalData() async{}

void populateDB() {
  try {
    final localDB = LocalDatabase.instance;
    localDB.dropDB(recreateDB: true).then((_){
      print('DB recreated!');
    }).then((_) {
      _insertInitialData();
      print('_insertInitialData done');
    }).then(() {
      _insertAdditionalData();
      print('_insertAdditionalData done');
    });
  } catch (ex) {
    print('There was a problem in populateDB(): $ex');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your way, Dan's way and my way are doing the same!!! My problem is internally in those other methods as they are also calling Future to insert data in the DB. Well, that's my theory. Will check and update this post.

Answer (score 1):

Cool. Thanks for your comments. I replaced all of those `Future.wait` for `async/await` even in my internal methods that insert into the DB and it's all good!!! (executing in the sequence I need)

Just learning Dart/Flutter for fun and I love it.